# iOS - Error when executing sfmc_setEventDelegate

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush-ios

I'm getting this error log in some situations which I haven't identified yet.

```
<MarketingCloudSDK+Base.m:(409)> iOS file protection is enabled and data is not available even after 5 seconds of waiting
```

This happens when I execute `sfmc_setEventDelegate`, but it's not a pattern, for instance, I can't replicate it locally. I just noticed it started spiking in Firebase as a Non-Fatal log, when we released MarketingCloud integration in our app.

`sfmc_setEventDelegate` is being called in the app delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

This is only happening in our production environment (our non-prod environment applications) aren't getting the same issue.

I double checked and our app doesn't use Data Protection, so, I'm not really sure how to interpret this issue... any help is appreciated.

Another thing that's weird and I cannot really explain is, the crash is being reported to be when I execute `sfmc_setEventDelegate`, although the error logging is being sent to firebase on the `catch` clause of the `configure` method of the MarketingCloud SDK.

````
        do {
            try client.configure(with: builder)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            // Errors returned from configuration will be in the NSError parameter and can be used to determine
            // if you've implemented the SDK correctly.
            Dependencies.logNonFatalError(SalesforceError.configurationError(error))
        }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure you are waiting for the `client.configure(with: builder)` to finish before setting any values on the SDK singleton including `sfmc_setEventDelegate`. The configure method is what is initializing the SDK, and setting values/delegates before the try catch finishes may result in undefined behavior.

Comment: thanks Skyler! :)